# Is it possible to pass basic auth to python Pandas get json data (pd.read_json)

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read JSON data from the web, which requires authentication, is that possible to pass authentication details to pd.read_json or I must use requests for this?

`df = pd.read_json("https://myurl.com/data.json", lines=False, auth=('username', 'password'))`

Answer (score 5):

```
import requests    

r = requests.get('https://intranet.jsondata.com/xy.json', auth=('user', 'pass'))
json_content = r.json()
```

will get you the json

```
pd.read_json(json_content)
```

will read it.

Comment: I know its possible using requests, however, I was looking for pandas equivalent

Comment: Not to my knowledge,  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36688 this was the closest it got and it was not acted on.  You can lobby for it to be reopened

Comment: ok thanks, I am already using the method, I was hoping to avoid importing requests

Comment: I read that issue as it being completed, and `storage_options` for HTTP connections now allowing to set Headers. If I get it working, I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is:

```
auth_header = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {secret_token}"}
pd.read_json(file_url, storage_options=auth_header)
```

will use Bearer Token authentication for the underlying web request.

It was implemented with [this PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16716)